# Add same alphanumeric values in dictionary list python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
items = {1: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b'], 2: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b']}
```

I want to add the integer components of all "similar" values for each list.
(Similar means that the strings end with the same character.)

I want the final output to be:

```
items = {1: ['7a', '3c', '6b'], 2: ['7a', '3c', '6b']}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck at?

Comment: @cdarke: sets won't work as there are dupes in the lists.

Comment: Should be '6b' in the second list, not '7b', right?

Comment: @timegb I corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = {1: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b'],
         2: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b']}

for key, value in items.items():
    counting = defaultdict(int)
    for elem in value:
        counting[elem[1]] += int(elem[0])
    items[key] = [str(v) + k for k,v in counting.items()]

print(items)
```

Comment: You could do `counting  = collections.defaultdict(int)` and then in the for loop just have `counting[elem[1]] += int(elem[0])` without having to check if the `elem1` is in `counting`

Comment: Thank you. I was trying with defaultdict but couldn't make it work. You tip helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following works, assuming that there's only one letter at the end of each string. Adjust indices accordingly if your alphanumeric strings are more complicated.

```
items = {1: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b'], 2: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b']}

def group_alphanum(alnums):
    import itertools
    alnums = sorted(alnums, key=lambda s: s[-1])
    for grp, items in itertools.groupby(alnums, key=lambda s: s[-1]):
        al = grp[-1]
        num = sum(int(item[:-1]) for item in items)
        yield "{}{}".format(num, al)

grouped_items = {k: list(group_alphanum(vals)) for k, vals in items.items()}
# {1: ['7a', '6b', '3c'], 2: ['7a', '6b', '3c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `itertools.groupby` function:

```
import itertools

items = {1: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b'], 2: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b']}
d = {}               # new dict
f = lambda x: x[-1]  # function to get the last char from each item

for key,l in items.items():
    d[key] = [ str(sum(int(n[:-1]) for n in g)) + k
               for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f) ]

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{1: ['7a', '6b', '3c'], 2: ['7a', '6b', '3c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one way to do it: (`d` is your original dictionary)

```
from itertools import groupby      
# iterate through the k,value pairs of the original dictionary 
for i, v in d.items():
     # sort the values of a list by the letters : a, b .. 
     v = sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[-1])
     summed_groups = []
     # groupby the elements of a list by the letters: a, b .. 
     for j, k in groupby(v, key=lambda x:x[-1]):
         # sum the int part of each group 
         sum_ints = sum([int(x.replace(j,'')) for x in k])
         # prepare the results 
         summed_groups.append("{}{}".format(sum_ints,j))
     d[i] = summed_groups
```

Results :

```
Out[13]: {1: ['7a', '6b', '3c'], 2: ['7a', '6b', '3c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
items = {1: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b'], 2: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b']}
new_items = {a:[(c, list(d)) for c, d in itertools.groupby(sorted(b, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])] for a, b in items.items()}
final_items = {a:[str(sum(int(i[0]) for i in d))+c for c, d in b] for a, b in new_items.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: ['7a', '6b', '3c'], 2: ['7a', '6b', '3c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution that uses `Counter`s to pre-process the original `items` dictionary, then the result is built from a dictionary with `Counter`s as values.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> items = {1: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b'], 2: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b']}
>>> tmp = {k: Counter(''.join(int(x[:-1])*x[-1] for x in v)) for k,v in items.items()}
>>> {k:[str(vv)+kk for kk,vv in v.items()] for k,v in tmp.items()}
{1: ['7a', '3c', '6b'], 2: ['7a', '3c', '6b']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
items = {1: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b'], 2: ['1a', '3c', '2a', '1b', '2a', '1b', '1a', '2b', '1a', '2b']}

for key in items:
    s = pd.Series(items[key])
    items[key] = [str(v.str[0].astype(int).sum())+k for k,v in s.groupby(s.str[1])]
print(items)
```